# error in setting default value to table field in create stetment

Tags: mysql, select

This is error in my sql stetment please help me at where its syntax mistake:

```
 CDbCommand failed to execute the SQL statement: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 Erreur de syntaxe près de '`Employee`,`fd` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT `hari`,PRIMARY KEY (id))' à la ligne 1. The SQL statement executed was: CREATE TABLE `form2` (`id` INT(10),`firstname` VARCHAR(20),`lastname` VARCHAR(20),`Age` INT(10),`Address` TEXT(100),`bd` INT(10),`bussiness` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT `Employee`,`fd` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT `hari`,PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Put single quote to default value like `'Employee'` instead of `back ticks`. try following query

```
CREATE TABLE `form2`(
`id` INT(10),
`firstname` VARCHAR(20),
`lastname` VARCHAR(20),
`Age` INT(10),
`Address` TEXT(100),
`bd` INT(10),
`bussiness` VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Employee',  
`fd` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hari', 
PRIMARY KEY (id));
```

**Changed `Employee` to 'Employee' and `hari` to 'hari'**

Comment: @user3640336 Never forgot accept/upvote when answer is helpful

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE `form2`
(
`id` INT(10),
`firstname` VARCHAR(20),
`lastname` VARCHAR(20),
`Age` INT(10),
`Address` TEXT(100),
`bd` INT(10),
`bussiness` VARCHAR(20) Not Null  DEFAULT 'Employee',
`fd` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'hari',
 PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

execute that one put character in single quot 'Employee' and 'Hari'